# SSRS graph with optional decimal positions

Tags: ssrs-2008

Is is possible to show optional decimal numbers for the values in the graph? I want to show up to 2 decimal values but only if the user inputs them. If the value is 9.34, I want it to show that. But if the value is just 9, I want it to show just 9. If the users types 9.3 then only that should be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that by converting the decimal value to a string and then using format characters like this:

```
=Format(CStr(Fields!a.Value),"#.##");
```

The `#` character will only diplay if a decimal value exists.  ( fyi, if you wanted the opposite from the format string, using 0.00 would force display zero's even if the values were integers ).

You can also use a combination such as 0.## or 0#.##

Further:

You can also just place that format string in the Custom option under Number in properties.

Comment: No need to convert to string. I went to the series label properties, then Number, selected Custom and typed the format you mentioned.

Comment: Cool, I knew the format character would work on a string so... good to know on the other as well.  Updated answer for future visitors.